# How to use python to read and write a register via LLDB?

Tags: python, ios, debugging, trace, lldb

I'm trying to use python to read/write a register when it hits the breakpoint.

I was able to execute a simple python script when a breakpoint is triggered.

The problem I'm having is reading and writing a single register. I can get a list of registers, but not a register.

```
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x000000010521562c dyld` ImageLoaderMachO::usablePrebinding(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) const  + 56
dyld`ImageLoaderMachO::usablePrebinding:
->  0x10521562c <+56>: ldrb   w8, [x19, #0x76]
    0x105215630 <+60>: ldrh   w9, [x19, #0x74]
    0x105215634 <+64>: bfi    w9, w8, #16, #8
    0x105215638 <+68>: tbz    w9, #0x9, 0x105215694     ; <+160>
    0x10521563c <+72>: ldr    x8, [x19]
    0x105215640 <+76>: ldr    x8, [x8, #0x378]
    0x105215644 <+80>: mov    x0, x19
    0x105215648 <+84>: blr    x8
Target 0: (BBM) stopped.
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> print lldb.frame.registers
```

Can anyone help me which python api I can use to change the x1 register value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `registers` property on SBFrames is an `SBValueList` that stores the sets of registers (GPR's, etc.).  Each register set is an SBValue, and the individual registers are represented as children of the register set, with the child name being the register name.  `x1` is a GPR, and the GPR's are always the first register set in `registers`.  `SBValueList` also `GetFirstValueByName` to get an  element by name, so you can also find the "General Purpose Register"'s programmatically.

So you would do something like:

```
error = lldb.SBError()
did_change = lldb.frame.registers[0].GetChildMemberWithName('x1').SetValueFromCString("0x12345",error)
```

`SetValueFromCString` returns `True` if it was able to change the value, and if it wasn't, the reason why will be stored in the `error` parameter.

Note that volatile registers like `x1` aren't stored across function calls, so you can only access or change their values in the currently executing frame.

SBValues are described here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/lldb.SBValue-class.html

if you want to know what else you can do with them.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the `registers` property, is the `register` property. It's a convenience for accessing registers by name. For example:

```
(lldb) script print lldb.frame.register["x1"].value
(lldb) script lldb.frame.register["x1"].value = "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dave Lee's answer worked in the `script` interface of `lldb`.

When I tried the same in a full script, I was getting null register values.

The documentation https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html explained all.  You needed to pass in **exe_ctx** to get the correct `context`.  This was the `lldb.SBExecutionContext`.

```
def YDFooBarFunction(debugger, command, exe_ctx, result, internal_dict):
    """
        Reads and writes a register.
    """
    frame = exe_ctx.frame
    error = lldb.SBError()
    disposition = frame.FindRegister("rsi")
    print("[*]Original register: " + str(disposition))

    if disposition.unsigned == 2:
        print "[!]found 2 in the register"
        result = frame.registers[0].GetChildMemberWithName('rsi').SetValueFromCString("0x1", error)
        messages = {None: 'error', True: 'pass', False: 'fail'}
        print ("[*]PATCHING result: " + messages[result])

    thread = frame.GetThread()
    process = thread.GetProcess()
    process.Continue()
```

I hope this saves people hours of hunting.

Note, I used part of the great man's ( @Jim Ingham's ) answer to write a register.